# How to get onNotification callback invoked when notification is received instead of tapped on an Android device

Tags: android, push-notification, react-native

Using zo0r react-native-push-notification https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification
the app is able to receive push notifications from server both when the app is in background and foreground. If the app is open it needs to act immediately on data provided in the notification, and when in background, it needs to act on the data when the app is opened.

However, the `onNotification` callback is only invoked when notification is tapped by the user. In my case I would like to have the callback invoked right away when the user opens the app (if background), and immediately if the app is in foreground. How can that be achieved for an android device? It works fine on iOS.